# Delete specific Delta Lake table versions?

Tags: delta-lake

Noting that time travel in Delta is not meant to be a permanent history, is there a method to delete specific versions of a table to keep fewer long term history versions for time travel?

The idea here being daily versions for the current 30 day window, then weekly or monthly versions only for older periods (for example deleting all but the 1st of the month), to provide some historical data with managed table size on disk.

This could be implemented by a process that saves off history in non-Delta Parquet tables, but keeping everything in one place would be preferable.